# Range query with Parse

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

How do you do range query with Parse:

Say I have this object:

```json
{
  "name": "YogaClub",
  "schedules": [
    {
      "day": "monday",
      "opens": 25200000000000,
      "closes": 39600000000000
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I query for `schedules` having day of "*monday*" and opens-closes that is in range of given two values say: `opens: 26000000000000` and `closes: 30000000000000`

Comment: What is the SDK that you are using?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo REST API

Answer (score 2):

Using the REST API, you can query like this:

```sh
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATION_ID" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: REST_API_KEY" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"schedules.day","monday","schedules.opens":{"$lte": 39600000000000},"schedules.closes":{"$gte": 25200000000000}}' \
  https://your.api.address/parse/classes/YourClassName
```